# How to tell if the covariant derivative of something is timelike or spacelike

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, vectors, covariance

How can I tell if the covariant derivative of something is timelike or spacelike?

Comment: What do you mean "how can you tell"? If you know the definition of timelike/spacelike, what trouble do you have in computing that definition?

Comment: Just as you compute whether a vector is timelike/spacelike, you can compute the 'norm' of the covariant derivative of a vector, since that is also a vector. The same applies for higher rank tensors.

Comment: I am thinking specifically of transforming to a new time coordinate and making sure it's timelike.